# Show/Hide multiple <span> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide multiple  elements in my table when a button is clicked. The table is generated using a PHP for loop

```
echo "<tr> ";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$stock_date</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$store_name</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$store_city</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($opening_stock,2)." <br/> </td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($wastage,2)."</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($purchases,2)." <br/>";
echo "<span id='averages' style='visibility:hidden;'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($avg_purch,2)."</span></td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($sales,2)."</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($closing_stock,2)."</td>";
```

Then I have the jQuery doing the following

```
$('#show_averages').click(function(event){


if(document.getElementById("averages").style.visibility == 'hidden')
{
        document.getElementById("averages").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

else if(document.getElementById("averages").style.visibility == 'visible')
{
        document.getElementById("averages").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

});
```

However it only works for the first id="averages" that it finds. How can I make it so that it shows all the  elements with id="averages"?

Comment: Id should be unique so use class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IDs (#) are used to identify elements on the page that only occur ONCE.** As soon as you have a duplicate, you can press F12 to open developer console and you should see an error saying it found two or more elements with the same ID. When you want to have multiple instances of something with the same properties, you can give it a **CLASS (.)**

Instead of using an id selector (#), change your td elements to have be classed together like this:

```
echo "<tr> ";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$stock_date</td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$store_name</td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$store_city</td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($opening_stock,2)." <br/> </td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($wastage,2)."</td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($purchases,2)." <br/>";
                        echo "<span class='averages' style='visibility:hidden;'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($avg_purch,2)."</span></td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($sales,2)."</td>";
                        echo "<td style='text-align:center'>$global_currency_sign ".number_format($closing_stock,2)."</td>";
```

Then select your elements like this:

```
$('#show_averages').on('click', function(){

//your code here

})
```

Note that you'll likely have to change your jQuery (or raw JS in your case) to select by classname, as they no longer have the ID from before. You'll have to use something like this in your code, if you're choosing to use vanilla JS:

```
Document.getElementsByClassName('averages')
```

Otherwise, you can select all of these elements with

```
var myAverages = $('.averages');

myAverages.each(function(){

  //this will loop through each of the average td elements and perform whatever code youd like here. You can reference each element with

  $(this).whatever....

})
```

Comment: I have tried that and I am getting an error `myaccount.php:637 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (myaccount.php:637)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)`

Comment: That means when your trying to get your object, it is returning undefined. You aren't referencing your object properly. Try using jQuery instead... something like if($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden'){ //some code... }

Comment: Great, got the if statement to work. Now the error that I am getting is when trying to change the css to visible. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` when trying to do ` $('.averages').css('visibility') = 'visible';`. What's the proper way of changing it to visible?

Comment: Like this: $('.averages').css('visibility', 'visible');

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you, sir!

Comment: No worries -- best of luck on your project! Also, I would consider looking into learning Laravel, or a templating language once you have a little more programming experience. It makes these types of things with PHP much much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Because ID of element should be always unique. You repeated the same ID again and again through a loop but when you selected it through jQuery **it selects only only first occurrence with the ID**. The solution to this is you should always prefer using **class** instead of ID when you're getting data through looping